# Randomly selecting a value (from a subset of values) at even distribution within a group in excel

Tags: excel, random, statistics, distribution

I have an excel document with the the following values (only those that are relevant here are provided).

For the value column, I want to select from the values 200, 400, 600, and apply them randomly to each row. Beyond this, I need to have an even distribution within each ID (therefore each ID would have 200 twice, 400 twice, 600 twice).

currently, I have been using this excel formula `=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),200,400,600)` in the value column, which randomly selects from the three values, but obviously does not provide an even distribution within each ID group (although it may in certain instances by chance).

```
ID  value
1   x
1   x
1   x
1   x
1   x
1   x
1   x
2   x
2   x
2   x
2   x
2   x
2   x
3   x
3   x
3   x
3   x
3   x
3   x
```

Does anyone have a solution for this, either in Excel or Python?

Comment: The distribution within groups will be even. The shares are not equal because of the deviation. To get equal shares but random assignment within groups you may use `shuffle ([200,200,400,400,600,600])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are exactly six values in each group, you could use a set-up like this in most versions of Excel:

```
=INDEX(E$2:E$7,RANK(B2,INDEX(B$2:B$19,QUOTIENT(ROW()-2,6)*6+1):INDEX(B$2:B$19,QUOTIENT(ROW()+4,6)*6)))
```

You need to create a helper column B containing random numbers, then use rank to select one of the values in the list based on the random numbers in the current block - method based on [this useful article](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/07/22/random-sample-excel-no-duplicates/)

[image]

Tip - you may find it easier to generate the random numbers in another column using rand(), then use paste values to put them in column B so they don't keep changing.

*Note* The article does consider how to deal with the situation where two of the generated random numbers are equal, but the chances of this happening are vanishingly small so I haven't included it in my answer.